# Encoding String to Bytes in Python

Tags: python, encryption, encoding

I have been trying to encode an encrypted text by taking the input (encrypted text) from command line and encoding using the following code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys
a = sys.argv[1]
b = a.encode('utf-8')
print(a)
print('\n')
print(b)
```

OUTPUT:

```
$python3 test.py 'b\x90\x89\xc6g\xa6\x15I\x9bKD\xd4s\xf2\x9f\x82Y\xedaa}0wL'

b\x90\x89\xc6g\xa6\x15I\x9bKD\xd4s\xf2\x9f\x82Y\xedaa}0wL

b'b\\x90\\x89\\xc6g\\xa6\\x15I\\x9bKD\\xd4s\\xf2\\x9f\\x82Y\\xedaa}0wL'
```

I need the exact same output which i input from terminal just in bytes to perform the decryption operation. When i try to replace it by the following code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys
a = sys.argv[1]
b = a.encode('utf-8').replace('\\','\')
print(a)
print('\n')
print(b)
```

OUTPUT:

```
$python3 test.py 'b\x90\x89\xc6g\xa6\x15I\x9bKD\xd4s\xf2\x9f\x82Y\xedaa}0wL'

File "testsys.py", line 6
  b = a.encode('utf-8').replace('\\','\')
                                      ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

I don't know about the error but in the line :

`b = a.encode().replace('\\\','\'`**)**

but the parenthesis in bold is still colored like a **string**.

How can I get the exact same string just in bytes ?

Comment: i am using python3

Comment: I find the responses here frustrating. This appears to be exactly the question I'm looking to have answered, just in another context. The answer is obviously to encode the string in something other than a UTF, because UTF encodings deliberately do not output all possible combinations of bytes. But the difficulty is, what encodings are viable for this? I've found *some* that won't raise an exception, but they consistently change the data.

Answer (score 0):

\' is an escaped single quote character.
\\ is an escaped backslash character.

The quote for the string never got closed

Answer (score 0):

You are escaping the closing `'`

```
b = a.encode('utf-8').replace('\\','\')
```

should be:

```
b = a.encode('utf-8').replace('\\','\'')
```

Comment: TypeError: expected bytes, bytearray or buffer compatible object

Answer (score 0):

The data you provided cannot be encoded with utf-8.

```
a = 'b\x90\x89\xc6g\xa6\x15I\x9bKD\xd4s\xf2\x9f\x82Y\xedaa}0wL'
>>> b = a.encode('utf-8')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x90 in position 1: ordinal
not in range(128)
```

If it actually works for you did you check decrypting the encoded string and did you get a different answer than the original string. Because by encoding the string with utf-8 doesn't mean that you are changing the integrity of the data.

Comment: Yes the code is working correctly on python interpreter